# getJSON google maps Polyline

Tags: google-maps, getjson, polyline

This is an example from my jsonData:

```
"lineformap":"new google.maps.LatLng(52.25602231800669, 6.160540580749512),new google.maps.LatLng(52.25543780780041, 6.1602723598480225),new google.maps.LatLng(52.255818725438296, 6.160014867782593)"
```

and this is my code:
(no line appears)
When i copy the data in to the code the lines are visable on the map
Who can help me with this

```
var poly;
var map;
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.2554, 6.1627);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

    var bermudaTriangle;

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("ObjectMap"), myOptions);
    $.getJSON('/api/dbklineforbws', function (createbws) {
        $(createbws).each(function (i, itemb) {
            // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
            var flightPlanCoordinates = [
            itemb.lineformap
          ];

            var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: flightPlanCoordinates,
                geodesic: true,
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2
            });



            flightPath.setMap(map);
        });
    });
    }


    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it's very strange usage of json file. But, to make it work I'd change json file to:

```
{
"lineformap": "[new google.maps.LatLng(52.25602231800669, 6.160540580749512),new google.maps.LatLng(52.25543780780041, 6.1602723598480225),new google.maps.LatLng(52.255818725438296, 6.160014867782593)]"
}
```

and

```
var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    itemb.lineformap
];
```

to

```
var flightPlanCoordinates = eval(itemb.lineformap);
```

to get polyline.